# Django Reverse function not working in this example

Tags: python, django

I'm not able to access the url named "forum" using the reverse function. It gives me this error:

django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'forum' not found. 'forum' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I'm able to access all my other namespaces URLs within the other apps. But I just can't access anything by name from my root URLs.py file.

Here is my root URLs.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from machina import urls as machina_urls
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('forum/',include(machina_urls), name='forum'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('symposium/', include('symposium.urls')),
    path('elearning/', include('elearning.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: why do you want to use your root Url and what do you expect to show when you reverse to 'forum' ? your machina app's index page ??

Comment: where else would I put my machinas URL include? And yes. I just want the name forum to take me where /forum takes me.

Comment: why not point to the name of the index of the machina app like reverse('machina:name_of_the_index_in_machina_app')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
from machina import urls as machina_urls
```

Change the url to this:

```
path('forum/', include(machina.urls),),
```

in the urls.py file of machina add above the urlpatterns:

```
app_name = 'machina'
```

If you are going to use reverse remember:

```
reverse('app_name:url_name')
```

For example we have the following url in our machina.urls:

```
path('bitcoin/', views.bitcoin, name='bitcoin'),
```

Your reverse would look like this:

```
reverse('machina:bitcoin')
```

docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#include << Class based overview

Examples: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#namespaces-and-include << Copy and write overview

Other option is to have a separate file with url pattern lists for example:

url_list.py

```
from django.urls import path
from yesyes import views

varvar = [
    path('', views.testbased, name='index'),
]
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from yesyes.url_list import varvar as urllist

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('test/',include(urllist), name='test'),
]
```

Comment: I don't have an app folder for Machina. Is there a solution where I don't have to make one?

Comment: Yes its possible, regarding to the include() function it also can handle a pattern_list. So you can make a url_list.py file and make urlpatterns lists and give them different variables and import them as you want and put them in the include args and that should do the job, did update the code section also for you

Comment: How is the second example different than what I have? I already have it including another file.     ```path('forum/',include(machina_urls), name='forum'),```
What is the reason my name=forum does not resolve in my case, and why would it resolve in your second example?

Comment: from <appname>.<py file> import <var of the list> as <name that you like>

Comment: if the file is in the same directory you can skipp apname and continue with .<py file>